# Linux kernel IRQ to execute long action

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, isr, irq, power-off

I am implementing a kernel module to handle power-off event. Our HW setup will emit an IRQ when power cut-off happens, and device can run 200ms more after that. During this time I have to close all rw-opened Fd to avoid file corruption. I am thinking of two options:

1. Perform closing all Fds from within the interrupt context itself. It will mask all other interrupts and handle the event until device is off. It may cause freezing issue.
2. Use Softirqs and do closing in the bottom half.

What would be the best way to implement this? thanks all.

Comment: bottom half. doing it in the isr  can block other interrupts needed to do close.

Comment: @stark: but when power is running out we no longer care about other interrupts?

Comment: You care about close completing?

Comment: @stark: But the interrupt will get fd_table and do fd closing by itself, it does not need other interrupt to do it? or pls correct me if i am wrong

Comment: close flushes all buffered data to disk. disk writes are asynchronous and interrupt on completion.

Comment: thanks stark, is there a way to clear buffered data before closing so I don't need other async action? and this flush takes long time so definitely i dont want to flush

Comment: If the file is opened with the O_SYNC flag, then there will be no buffered data.